# the directory for cakephp in xml generation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I uploaded xml file in my cakephp in img/files directory

app->webroot->files->Myfile.xml

and I want to call it from my controller like this

$file = "/files/Myfile.xml";

I am not sure is this the correct path from the controller ot not
of course controller is in app->controllers->my_controller

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of the [CakePHP Core Configuration Constants](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1141/Core-Definition-Constants).

`WWW_ROOT` for example:

```
$file = WWW_ROOT . "files/MyFiles.xml";
```